# Stm32F103 DMA TIM1 - Load 50% of period.

Tags: pwm, timer, dma

I wrote a code using DMA with TIM1. In DMA buffer i load diffrent periods and send to ARR Register. How Can I change a Pulse of PWM to 50% from Dma buffer ?

```
int i = 0;
volatile u16 PWM_Buf[20];
void TIMInit(void);
void GPIOInit(void);
void DMAInit(void);
void PWMInit(void);

int main(void) {
    GPIOInit();
    TIMInit();
    DMAInit();
    PWMInit();

    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        PWM_Buf[i] = i*100+300; //TU ŁADUJE WARTOSCI DO DMA ALE OKRES TIMERA SIE NIE ZMIENAI
    }

    while (1) {
    }
}
void TIMInit(void) {
    TIM_TimeBaseInitTypeDef TIMInit;

    RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_TIM1, ENABLE);

    //TIMInit.TIM_Period = 1000 - 1;
    TIMInit.TIM_Prescaler = 64000 - 1;
    TIMInit.TIM_ClockDivision = TIM_CKD_DIV1;
    TIMInit.TIM_CounterMode = TIM_CounterMode_Up;
    TIMInit.TIM_RepetitionCounter = 0;

    TIM_TimeBaseInit(TIM1, &TIMInit);
}

void GPIOInit(void) {
    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIOInit;

    RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_GPIOA, ENABLE);
    RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_AFIO, ENABLE);

    GPIOInit.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_8;
    GPIOInit.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF_PP;
    GPIOInit.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;

    GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIOInit);
}

void DMAInit(void) {

    DMA_InitTypeDef DMAInit;
    RCC_AHBPeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHBPeriph_DMA1, ENABLE);
    DMA_DeInit(DMA1_Channel5);
    DMAInit.DMA_PeripheralBaseAddr = (u32)&TIM1 -> ARR && (u32)&TIM1 -> CCR1;
    DMAInit.DMA_MemoryBaseAddr = (u32) PWM_Buf;
    DMAInit.DMA_DIR = DMA_DIR_PeripheralDST;
    DMAInit.DMA_BufferSize = 20;
    DMAInit.DMA_PeripheralInc = DMA_PeripheralInc_Disable;
    DMAInit.DMA_MemoryInc = DMA_MemoryInc_Enable;
    DMAInit.DMA_PeripheralDataSize = DMA_PeripheralDataSize_Word;
    DMAInit.DMA_MemoryDataSize = DMA_MemoryDataSize_HalfWord;
    DMAInit.DMA_Mode = DMA_Mode_Circular;
    DMAInit.DMA_Priority = DMA_Priority_High;
    DMAInit.DMA_M2M = DMA_M2M_Disable;
    DMA_Init(DMA1_Channel5, &DMAInit);

    DMA_Cmd(DMA1_Channel5, ENABLE);
}

void PWMInit(void) {
    TIM_OCInitTypeDef PWMInit;

    PWMInit.TIM_OCMode = TIM_OCMode_PWM1;
    PWMInit.TIM_OutputState = TIM_OutputState_Enable;
    PWMInit.TIM_Pulse = 5;
    PWMInit.TIM_OCPolarity = TIM_OCPolarity_High;
    TIM_OC1Init(TIM1, &PWMInit);
    //TIM_OC1PreloadConfig(TIM1, TIM_OCPreload_Enable);
    //TIM_ARRPreloadConfig(TIM1, ENABLE);
    TIM_DMACmd(TIM1, TIM_DMA_Update, ENABLE);
    TIM_Cmd(TIM1, ENABLE);
    TIM_CtrlPWMOutputs(TIM1, ENABLE);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`DMAInit.DMA_PeripheralBaseAddr = (u32)&TIM1 -> ARR && (u32)&TIM1 -> CCR1;`
It is unclear what you are doing here.

If you want two registers as destination, you will need two DMA channels.

The DMAInit.DMA_PeripheralBaseAddr (DMA_CPARx) register only takes one address.

Comment: You can write to multiple timer registers (for TIM1 and TIM8) using 1 DMA channel, by configuring TIM1->DCR and using TIM1->DMAR as the peripheral base address.